How to use PowerFX to navigate to a specific form in PowerApp?
Im building a model driven PowerApp. For one Dataverse Table I wanted to add buttons in the command bar to edit these in specific forms.
I found this in the documentation: Microsoft Documentation
Navigate(Self.Selected.Item) works like a charm, but uses the last used form every time. Adding arguments like in the documentation seems to not work.
Navigate(Self.Selected.Item) 
--> works (The selected entry opens (but not with a specific form))

Navigate(Self.Selected.Item, ...) 
--> does not work (',' seems to be wrong in my region, so I used ';'

Navigate(Self.Selected.Item; { Page: '[TableNamePlural] (Forms)'.[TableNameSingular] } ) 
--> does not work (as expected but this is the offical documentation) 
Error: Invalid argument: "Page" should refer to a specific entity form or custom page

Navigate(Self.Selected.Item; { Page: '[TableNamePlural] (Forms)'.[Name of Form] } ) 
--> does not work
Error: Invalid argument: "Page" should refer to a specific entity form or custom page

Navigate(Self.Selected.Item; { Page: [Name of Form] } )
--> same

Navigate(Self.Selected.Item; { Page: '[Name of Form]' } )
--> same

Anyone has an idea?
Thanks

The answer is pretty silly.
Thanks to this „programming language“ the language matters a lot.
As I’m in Germany the correct expression is „‚Name (Formulare)‘.Form“. (Formulare is German for Forms)
I can’t stress enough how much I dislike that, especially since the German documentation (I guess auto translated) does not mention this.

The formula that works for me is the one outlined in the official document:
Navigate(Self.Selected.Item, { Page: '[TableNamePlural] (Forms)'.[TableNameSingular] } ) 
If you face the Error: Invalid argument: "Page" should refer to a specific entity form or custom page error, you will need to go to the Command Bar Editor and select "Open component library" at the top right corner. In the Component Library, you will need to publish the component (or Ctrl + Shift + P).
After publish, the error shall go off.
